# Choosing a Random Background - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, random, background

I want to implement a 'random background' onto my website, so every time someone refreshes the page, they are greeted with a new background. I unfortunately cannot use PHP, for which I found this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/ which though was kind of useful for learning, I couldn't actually use it.

My current code:

```
.mainview {
    background-image: url(images/bg-1.png);
    height: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px
}
```

Instead of the URL being set to one image, I want it to pick a random one from a list of three I have (bg-1,bg-2,bg-3). How would I do this?

Comment: you'll need to use Javascript of some server side script. To my knowledge this can't be done in pure CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an array of images, use `Math.random()` to get a random index and use that index to get a random image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var images = ['image-1.jpg', 'image-2.jpg', 'image-3.jpg', 'image-4.jpg'];
  document.getElementsByClassName('mainview')[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')';

</script>
```